# retrieve multiple values from Dropdown menu in Django

Tags: django

I have a form well rendered in my template with a dropdown menu and a save button, when i choose an item from the dropdown menu and click save, I pass to the views.py the url for that item, like this:

```
<select name="listxblocks">
  {% for scname, desc in scenarios %}
    <option value="{% url "workbench_show_scenario" scname %}">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now, in the views.py file i can retrieve the selected item and it's value,

```
if request.method == "POST": #checks if the request is a POST operation
    url = request.POST['listxblocks']
```

but i want also to retrieve the name **scname** and the description **desc**

I tried with hidden field but it made my template messy, how can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for retrive all information from your select.

1) Take ***all*** data from select.
   in the view use the following code:

```
variable = request.POST.getlist('listxblocks')
```

2) add "multiple" to your select like

```
<select name="listxblocks" multiple="multiple">
      {% for scname, desc in scenarios %}
      <option value="{% url "workbench_show_scenario" scname %}">{{desc}}/{{scname}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

in view.py using

```
url = request.POST['listxblocks']
```

you will find a list with all selected options

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However i think you misunderstood my problem. I'm not looking to select multiple items from the dropdown menu (i guess the title is wrong), i'm looking to select only one item and retrieve multiple infos about it, in my template i specified the url as the information to be retrieved, but i need another two informations to pass to the view