# Django Display Multiple Values from Dependent Dropdown

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, ajax

I'm using Python 3.8 & Django 3.0 and need multiple values (volume & volume size) to go to a dependent dropdown. I've been able to populate the dependent dropdown with a single value (volume). I found posts that work with a dropdown
[sending multiple values from django dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045932/sending-multiple-values-from-django-dropdown)
and
[retrieve multiple values from Dropdown menu in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404305/retrieve-multiple-values-from-dropdown-menu-in-django) but these don't work with a dependent dropdown.
Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class ArrayVolumes(models.Model):
    array = models.ForeignKey(Array, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    vol_size = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.volume
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import ArrayVolumes

def load_volumes(request):
    array_id = request.GET.get('array')
    vols = ArrayVolumes.objects.filter(array_id=array_id).order_by('volume')
    # vol_size = ArrayVolumes.objects.filter(array_id=array_id).value('vol_size')
    return render(request, 'pure/volume_dropdown_list_options.html', {'vols': vols})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('ajax/load-volumes/', views.load_volumes, name='ajax_load_volumes'),
]
```

**dropdown_list_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for vol, size in vols %}
<option value="{{ vol.pk }}#{{ size }}">{{ vol.volume }} ( {{ size.vol_size }} )</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**main.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">

{% crispy form form.helper %}
<form method="post" id=volForm data-volumes-url="{% url 'ajax_load_volumes' %}" novalidate>
<br><br>
<h4>{{ note }}</h4>
</form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#id_array").change(function () {
        var url = $("#volForm").attr("data-volumes-url");
        var arrayId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            'array': arrayId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#id_volume").html(data);
        }
        });

    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to pass all of `ArrayVolumes.objects` then loop over the items using `vol.volume` and `vol.vol_size` in the HTML file. Below are my modifications:

**views.py**

```
def load_volumes(request):
    array_id = request.GET.get('array')
    vols = ArrayVolumes.objects.filter(array_id=array_id)
    return render(request, 'pure/volume_dropdown_list_options.html', {'vols': vols})
```

**dropdown_list_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for vol in vols %}
<option value="{{ vol.pk }}">{{ vol.volume }} ( {{ vol.vol_size }} )</option>
{% endfor %}
```